# jquery location refresh beats fade out

Tags: jquery

jquery location refresh beats fade out in ajax callback method. Why?

```
        success: function (data) {
            $('#statusMessageDiv').show().fadeOut(1400);
            location.reload();
        }
```

If I comment the .reload, I see the fadeOut. However, if not commented I don't see the fadeout and the page just reloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation runs asynchronously, so it begins but is not waited for. The code execution continues to the `reload` call right away. To remedy this, you can move the reload to a callback function of the `fadeOut` method, which will be fired after the animation completes:

```
$('#statusMessageDiv').show().fadeOut(1400, function() {
    location.reload();
});
```

[jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/#fadeOut-duration-complete)